# How can I create real-time count in codeigniter using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

this is my view part:

```
<ul class="users-list clearfix">
                <?php if(!empty($adminslist)){
                    foreach($adminslist as $v){
        ?>
                    <li class="selectVendor" id="<?=$v['admin_id'];?>" title="<?=$v['fname'];?>">
                      <img src="<?=base_url('/assets/uploads/' . $v['img']);?>" alt="<?=$v['fname'];?>" title="<?=$v['fname'];?>">
                      <a class="users-list-name" href="#"><?=$v['fname'];?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php }?>

               <?php }else{?>
                <li>
                   <a class="users-list-name" href="#">No Admin Find...</a>
                 </li>
                <?php } ?>


              </ul>
```

and This is my mysql Part which is i used in this:-

```
<?php

                        $this->load->model(['OuthModel','UserModel']);

                        $list = $this->UserModel->adminList();
                        foreach ($list as $admin) {
                            $this->db->select('count(*) as count');
                            $this->db->from("chat");
                            $this->db->where("receiver_id", $this->session->userdata('id'));
                            $this->db->where("chat_status", "1");
                            $this->db->where("sender_id", $admin['id']);
                            $result1 = $this->db->get();
                            $count = $result1->result_array();
                            $final=$count[0]['count'];
                            if($this->OuthModel->Encryptor('decrypt', $v['admin_id']) == $admin['id']) {
                            ?>
                              <span class="label label-pill" style="border-radius:10px;color: black;"><?php echo $final?></span>
                            <?php }
                        }
                      ?>
```

i didn't try any code of ajax for live count i tried ajax code for all no. of rows count and call and it is give me all count and i want specific admin/user count or row for notification. and in php code it is run successfully but not giving live count.

and it is my ajax which i used:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
 {

  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Notify/index",
   method:"POST",
   data:{"view":view},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
      $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);
      $('.count').show();
      if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
      {    
         $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
      }  else if(data.unseen_notification == ''){
         $('.count').hide();
      }
   }
  });
 }
 load_unseen_notification();
 $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){
  $('.count').html('');
  load_unseen_notification('yes');
 });
 setInterval(function(){
 load_unseen_notification();
 }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: get ajax response in variable and use async in ajax

Comment: and how i can call this because i have to return the id and my id is in foreach condition and it is giving me last id

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Sockets](https://techalltype.com/myblog/real-time-notification-using-socket-io-in-codeigniter/). If I'm guessing right, the one you are after is a continuous data-get function. You should really use a websocket.